# (React) How to put focus on first element when component updates?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in react. 
In `ParentComponent`, I render either first or second panel depending on whether certain conditions are met. Let's say `FirstPanel` is rendered.
Inside `FirstPanel`, I am able to do some interactions that would update the panel and I need the focus to go to the first element in the first panel (aka the first div element)
How can I do this? I tried using `this.props.setRef.focus()` but it doesn't work.

**ParentComponent**

```
setCurrentPanel(panel) {
    this.currentPanel = panel;
}

render() {
    if (this.state.showFirstPanel)
        return <FirstPanel setRef={this.setCurrentPanel} />;
    if (this.state.showSecondPanel)
        return <SecondPanel setRef={this.setCurrentPanel} />;
    return undefined;
}
```

**FirstPanel**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // put focus on component FirstPanel again
}
render() {
    return <div role="tabpanel" tabIndex="0" ref={this.props.setRef}>
       {children}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `createRef`? https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#programmatically-managing-focus

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `ParentComponent` implementation, when the state changes, `FirstPanel` will unmount, and then `SecondPanel` mounts.

When you switch again, `SecondPanel` unmounts, and `FirstPanel` mounts.

To achieve what you are after, simply do the focus manipulation in both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` lifecycles.

In addition, if your `ParentComponent` is not going to anything with `currentPanel`, you can `creatRef` in each Panel component. Your `setRef` at the moment is simply an function, not a Ref object that contains reference to the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Using useRef and useEffect you can do that way:

```
import React , {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const MyComponent = () => {
const [valueThatWillChange, setValueWillChange] = useState(null);
const ref = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.focus();
}, [valueThatWillChange]);

return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={ref} />
      <input type="text" onBlur={e => setValueThatWillChange(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Each time that the cursor out of second input he will back to the first one

Comment: What about the case where your div is a wrapper like `return (<div>{children}</div>)`